# Правильно ли использовать service в случае отправки данных?

Tags: java, android

В приложение экран регистрации поставлен не на первом экране и возникает проблема, так как пока юзер доходит до регистрации по пути сохраняются данные, которые отправляются на сервер после того как юзер пройдет регистрацию.

Но для регистрации нужен интернет, а если ситуация когда интернета нет, а данные уже подготовлены к отправке?

Я хочу использовать `service` для этого. Юзер нажимает на кнопку регистрации идет проверка соединения, если нет, то запускается сервис который бежит в бекграунде и проверяет каждую минуту соеденение как только появляется идет отправка данных и сервис уничтожается.

Вопрос в том :

1. насколько верно решение?
2. Не будет ли уничтожаться сервис при удалении приложения из задач
   выполнения или при перезагрузке устройства?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше вывести предупреждение, что интернет не доступен и регистрация не прошла, чтобы пользователь как то решал проблему отсутствия интернета - это нормальная практика, так как адекватный человек понимает, что для регистрации нужен интернет.
 Какая то отложенная регистрация неизвестно когда, я считаю крайне неудачное решение, она только введет пользователя в заблуждение.

Если вы хотите избавить пользователя от повторного ввода каких то данных, то сохраните их локально и подставляйте, когда пользователь будет проходить все заново, чтобы он мог либо просто нажимать далее, либо, в случае необходимости, что то исправить, хотя такой юзкейс и не обязателен, большинство регистраций просто отклоняется с уведомлением.

Так же вы можете проверять наличие интернета перед тем, как пользователь будет что то вводить и предупреждать, что дальнейшие действия требуют активного подключения к интернету.

Comment: Да я думаю это на самом деле перебор с идеей... Сделаю все проще следуя вашему совету, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Сервис может быть в любой момент прибит системой и данные будут потеряны. При перезапуске устройства сервис магически не восстановится, тем более со старыми данными.

Вам надо в этом случае просто записать данные для отправки в Preferences` а пытаться их отправить либо по рассписанию AlarmManager либо при входе в приложение

Comment: Мне кажется что на самом деле я переборщил с идеей)) Я проверил только, что несколько крупных апплекаций и они действительно делают проще, просто говорят юзеру, что нет соеденения. Наверное во избежание усложнения приложения и потери данных лучше всего сделать так... Но спасибо за совет